# How can I check if the managed property contains value?

Tags: managed-property, crawled-property

I have created a managed property in Central Admin which is mapped to Start Date crawled property. These are the settings which I have set on my managed property:

1. Type: Date and Time
2. Queryable: true
3. Retrievable: true
4. Refinable: true
5. Sortable: true
6. Mapped crawled Property: ows_q_DATE_StartDate

There is data in the lists, but the managed property does not return any values back. It is always empty.

Comment: Make sure you have performed a **Full Crawl** on the content source(s) that contain(s) the new managed property (see MSDN [Manage search schema > To add a managed property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx#proc2)).

Comment: I have performed a full crawl of the content source, but I am not getting anything for this particular managed property. I have mapped it to the "Start time" field in Calendar list

Answer (score 1):

**ows_EventDate** is the correct crawled property